# Nothing coming up in a GUI (Tkinter) window

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, label

I am writing a code for a login system using tkinter and for some reason when I run the code there are no error messages and a window pops up but without the title, buttons or labels I need.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

frame = Tk()

def adminlogincheck(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    if username == '123key' and password == 'key123':
      accept = Label(frame, text='Login Successful')
    else:
      decline = Label(frame, text='Login incorrect')
    mainloop()

def adminselect(self, master):
  frame = Frame(master)
  frame.pack()
  self.button = Button(frame, text="Cancel", fg="red", command=quit)
  self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
  self.slogan = Button(frame, text="Proceed", command=self.adminlogin)
  self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)
  mainloop()

def adminlogin(self, master):
  frame = Frame(master)
  frame.pack()
  username_entry = Entry(frame)
  password_entry = Entrey(frame)
  confirm = Button(frame, text='Login', command = adminlogincheck)
  loginquit = Button(frame, text='Cancel', command=quit)
  mainloop()
```

I will add more after the login system works but does anyone know why no buttons or labels appear?

Comment: You should only have one mainloop per script. Since mainloop is a blocking call that prevents the script to continue reading. Remove all your mainloop’s and add one to the end of your script

Comment: And every widget (label, entry, frame, etc.) must be packed to be displayed. The first and last functions have entries, labels and buttons that are not packed.

Comment: @RonNorris I have put the packs in various places but the same issue occurs. Is there anywhere in particular I need it.

Comment: @abccd I tried that and the same issue occured

Answer (score 0):

There's enough in your request to see what you're trying to accomplish, but there are many issues with the code. Here is a working model of what you appear to be working toward...

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


class Admin:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

    def logincheck(self):
        self.clearframe()
        if self.username.get() == '123key' and self.password.get() == 'key123':
            accept = Label(self.frame, text='Login Successful')
            accept.pack(side=LEFT)
        else:
            decline = Label(self.frame, text='Login incorrect')
            decline.pack(side=LEFT)

    def select(self):
        self.clearframe()
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text="Cancel", fg="red", command=quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.slogan = Button(self.frame, text="Proceed", command=self.adminlogin)
        self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)

    def login(self):
        self.clearframe()
        username_entry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.username)
        username_entry.pack()
        password_entry = Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.password)
        password_entry.pack()
        confirm = Button(self.frame, text='Login', command = self.logincheck)
        confirm.pack()
        loginquit = Button(self.frame, text='Cancel', command=quit)
        loginquit.pack()

    def clearframe(self):
        # Destroy all children of the class's frame.
        for child in self.frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

root = Tk()
admin = Admin(root)
admin.login()
mainloop()
```